# Angular/Typescript : How to properly initialize a FormControl of a union type?

Tags: typescript, types, enums, angular2-formbuilder

I have an issue with type-safety while initializing a form. My problem is the following :

I basically have an interface to describe a TypedForm with a property that should accept either Enum values or the string values of the Enum.

Here's for the Enum :

```
export enum MyEnum {
    FIRST_VALUE= 'FIRST_VALUE',
    SECOND_VALUE= 'SECOND_VALUE',
}
```

Here's for the Type that accepts either Enum or string values :

```
// similar to MyEnum | 'FIRST_VALUE' | 'SECOND_VALUE'
export type MyEnumKeyValues = MyEnum | keyof typeof StringEnum;
```

And the Form definition :

```
export type MyForm = FormGroup<{
    enumProperty: FormControl<MyEnumKeyValues>
}>
```

The problem is that, when i use FormBuilder to initialize my Form, the default value i pass in always throws a type error :

```
const myFormGroup: MyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    // TS2322 :  Type FormControl<MyEnum> is not assignable to FormControl<MyEnumKeyValues>
    enumProperty: MyEnum.FIRST_VALUE,
    // TS2322 :  Type FormControl<string> is not assignable to FormControl<MyEnumKeyValues>
    enumProperty: 'FIRST_VALUE',
    // Works but works with pretty much anything, that's not want we want here...
    enumProperty: 42 as MyEnumKeyValues,
});
```

Note that this works but it's ugly (my real life object is much bigger, with several Enums in it) :

```
const myFormGroup: MyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    enumProperty: new FormControl<MyEnumKeyValues>(MyEnum.FIRST_VALUE)
});
```

Is there a better / more elegant way to achieve this please ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the generic type `TValue` in `FormControl` is used as a function parameter in multiple methods. This makes the generic type [*contra-variant*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) which leads to an error when trying to assign `FormControl<MyEnum.FIRST_VALUE>` to `FormControl<MyEnumKeyValues>`.

One possible solution here would be to change the type of `myForm` to

```
export type MyForm = {
    enumProperty: MyEnumKeyValues
}
```

and using it when building the form like this:

```
const myFormGroup = formBuilder.group<MyForm>({
    enumProperty: MyEnum.FIRST_VALUE,
});
```

`enumProperty` will be type checked to be one of `MyEnumKeyValues`.

The type of `myFormGroup` is automatically inferred to

```
const myFormGroup: FormGroup<{
    enumProperty: FormControl<MyEnumKeyValues>;
}>
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/LAKAlgtgDg9gTgFwAQG8kDF4QOJxgVygBoMsBhGAOwTwBskBfJAMzwiQHIABAQ0oHN8tHnAD0zLAGcOAblCRYiVKTgQAQvjC0AJgFM4jFm068BQkeKmzQoXQA9FyXZXzsAsgE8Aoi-YpQSIEYAJIASgDKACoA%20gBqAIIAMgCqXgC8nOhhUXFJqRxEAUHhXmQA8gByACK5KemcJeXVtfmFIAw2IPaOSAgeULpInj6uANK6HrE8tPi6kkgZw75IAD5IANYTMMy9-brbQ96%20ciC2DvDIfQOHmKoLqEWBzq4ACngDiB4AXIcjEOOTaazSSgDqnEB6ADGwjgg0hVEkyAkqg0Wj0cB%20t3Umh0%20k6oHhlERSAgHixuAIUHuyOxaP0ADp%20HhCAAeTxYgB8AAp-CAgkhnhA3jAPn0fktXPSshEYgk6m0GABKGRIIA)